# How to query Box2D-bodies in a certain area?

Tags: java, scala, libgdx, box2d

I want to get all the Box2D bodies in a certain radius.

That for afaik I need to use a QueryCallback. I try it like this:

```
private def getBodies(position: Vector2, radius: Float): LibgdxArray[Body] =
{
    val lowerBound = new Vector2(position - radius)
    val upperBound = new Vector2(position + radius)

    val bodies: LibgdxArray[Body] = new LibgdxArray[Body]

    val callback: QueryCallback = new QueryCallback
    {
        override def reportFixture(fixture: Fixture): Boolean =
        {
            bodies.add(fixture.getBody)
            true
        }
    }

    world.queryAABB(callback, lowerBound.x, lowerBound.y, upperBound.x, upperBound.y)

    bodies
}
```

My problem is, that I always get an empty LibgdArray. Do I need to do something more than just call queryAABB on the world? Is my code not correct?

**edit**: Okay, I don't understand this at all: I set the radius to a bigger value. I can remove static bodies, but the dynamic bodies do not care at all :(

I add them like this:

```
if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.RIGHT))
{
      val mousePos: Vector3 = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX, Gdx.input.getY, 0)
      val worldPos = camera.unproject(mousePos)

  val ballShape: CircleShape = ShapeFactory.circle(new Vector2(worldPos.x, worldPos.y), 0.5f)
  val ballDef: BodyDef = new BodyDef
  ballDef.`type` = BodyType.DynamicBody
  val ballBody = world.createBody(ballDef)
  ballBody.createFixture(ballShape, 0.5f)

  ballShape.dispose
}
```

Comment: I've never used scala, but your code almost mirrors a similar method I wrote the other day in java (and is working for me), so I think you're on the right track. You should not need to do anything else. As long as your bounds are getting passed/set correctly, and of course you have bodies/fixtures in the radius range.

Comment: @PeterR Please see my update.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the queryAABB callback code vs. the "can remove static bodies but dynamic bodies do not care at all" vs. the dynamic circle creation code sample all relate. Sounds like something very specific to whatever you're implementing, but I don't see the connection. Are you sure your screen/world translations are correct? You're creating a new circle using screen positioning (pixels), but typically a box2d world is in meters. Most folks do a "pixel to meter" conversion (ie: 32 ppm). Maybe your calculations are mixing up units when you switch between box2d and Gdx.input calls.

Comment: @PeterR, nope I set the ppm only once, in the camera creation. Makes it way easier to handle that stuff without having to (re)calculate all the dimensions all the time. Like so:     camera = new OrthographicCamera(screenWidth / pixelsPerMeter, screenHeight / pixelsPerMeter) The relation is, that somehow the dynamic bodies do not get deleted, while the static ones do :(

Answer (score 0):

## Potential Solution

If you want to find all objects within a given area, one method is to first find the size of the smallest object in the world, then iteratively test all points in that area from your start point to your end point (assuming a rectangular area), with the iteration step being equal to half of the smallest size found (to avoid accidentally skipping over them).

### Example code:

Finding the smallest area iteration step:

```
public static float smallestStep(World world) {
    //Start min size at max float value
    Vector2 minSize = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    //Gets bodies in world
    Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
    world.getBodies(bodies);

    //Iterate over every body
    for(Body body: bodies) {
        //Iterate over each fixture for each body
        for(Fixture fixture : body.getFixtureList()) {
            //Get fixture shape
            Shape shape = fixture.getShape();

            //Check if shape's "radius" is smaller than current min value
            if(shape.getRadius() < minSize) {
                //Updates min size
                minSize = shape.getRadius();
            }
        }
    }

    //Returns half of the min found value
    return minValue / 2;
}
```

Testing if a fixture contains a given point is the next step, by iterating over all fixtures of a body and adding the body to a list if one of the fixtures of the body contains the point using the `fixture.testPoint()` method, you should be able to generate a list of all of the bodies that overlap the given point.